# JQuery picture load

Tags: jquery, gallery, image

I need some help in jQuery. What I'm trying to do is to create some sort of a small picture gallery. In this gallery I've got a couple of small pics and one big pic. By clicking a small picture I want jQuery to load and replace the big picture.

Here's a little try which does not work! But probably someone could tell me why.

```
$(function(){
   $("a.smallpics").click(function(e){
      $(".bigpic")
      .load(function () {
          $(this).hide();
          $('#loader')
            .append(this);
            .removeClass('loading')
          $(this).fadeIn();
      });
      .attr('src', this.href);
      e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

and the html

```
<a href="pic1_big.jpg" class="smallpics" /><img src="pic1_small.jpg" style="width: 20px; height: 20px" /></a>
<a href="pic2_big.jpg" class="smallpics" /><img src="pic2_small.jpg" style="width: 20px; height: 20px" /></a>
<a href="pic3_big.jpg" class="smallpics" /><img src="pic3_small.jpg" style="width: 20px; height: 20px" /></a>
<div id="loader" class="loading" /><img src="pic3_big.jpg" class="bigpic" /></div>
```

So in the best case the script would cover the big picture with a grey half transparent layer, start a spinner and after loading fading the picture in.
(Spinner is in background of class 'loading')

Thanks for your help.

Comment: From what I understand from your question you seem to want a jQuery gallery/slideshow thingie. There are many many plugins for this out there already. e.g. check this http://blueprintds.com/2009/01/20/top-14-jquery-photo-slideshow-gallery-plugins/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly you are getting a lot of js errors as you are not chaining things correctly, but the logic in your solution is a bit flawed also.

But if I understood your question correctly, you need to hide the bigpic *before* the `load` event, and on `load` event, show it again:

```
$(function(){
    $('a.smallpics').click(function() {        
        var $bigpic = $('.bigpic');
        var $loader = $('#loader').show();        
        $bigpic.hide().load(function () {
            $loader.fadeOut();
            $(this).fadeIn();
        }).attr('src', $(this).attr('href'));
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're sort of reinventing the wheel ... for the 4,000,000th time, but it's a good exercise for learning jQuery.

For debugging javascript on a web page nothing beats Firefox + Firebug plugin.

Comment: I was gonna suggest debugging as well... probably more valuable in terms of learning than simply seeing the correct answer here on SO. :)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out [this jQuery loader plugin](http://cloudgen.w0ng.hk/jquery/loader.php)... [or this one](http://www.tutcity.com/view/jquery-loader-plugin-for-images-and-divs.23662.html).